# How to change number in link in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I create slideshow, But i need load other image after click on the `next` or `prev` button.

For example:

```
<div class="photolist-photo" style="background-image: url('/site/img/100/1.jpg')">
<a class="left carousel-control" data-slide="prev" href="#myCarousel" role="button">
    <span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span> 
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
</a> 
<a class="right carousel-control" data-slide="next" href="#myCarousel" role="button">
    <span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span> 
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
</a>
```

I need just change `1.jpg` in `style="background-image: url('/site/img/100/1.jpg')"` to `2.jpg` after click on the `next` button.

How to get `1` and change to `2` in url?

Comment: Do you have more than two images or just 1 and 2 ?

Comment: What have you tried? You will need to set the whole "style" attribute using javascript/JQuery. So you should be tracking the current number that is being viewed, so you can adjust it and create the correct path with each button click

Comment: If you change anyhow nothing will happen. because image need to be page load to show

Comment: @DanPhilip, Hi, I need change to 3 and 4 and ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
start = 0;

$(function() {
  $('#next').click(function() {
    var current = start;
    start++;
    changeBackground(current , start);
  });
  
  $('#previous').click(function() {
    if (start != 0) {
      var current = start;
      start--;
      changeBackground(current , start);
    }
  });
});

function changeBackground(from, to) {
  var link = $('.photolist-photo').css('background-image');
  link = link.replace(from + '.jpg', to + '.jpg');
  console.log(link);
  $('.photolist-photo').css('background-image', link);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="photolist-photo" style="background-image: url('/site/img/100/1.jpg')">
<a class="left carousel-control" data-slide="prev" href="#myCarousel" role="button">
    <span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span> 
    <span class="sr-only" id="previous">Previous</span>
</a> 
<a class="right carousel-control" data-slide="next" href="#myCarousel" role="button">
    <span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span> 
    <span class="sr-only" id="next">Next</span>
</a>
```

Comment: @mySun changed the code, you should specify this before posting the question not editing after